# Смещение background-image

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Почему смещается фоновое изображение, если добавляю внешний отступ дочернему элементу?

```
<div class="contact__map"> // указываю фоновое изображение
    <div class="address"></div>  // внешний отступ сверху - смещается фон родителя 
</div>
```

[Код на codepen](http://codepen.io/anatolyrodin/pen/NxPYLV?editors=110#0).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если не ошибаюсь, свойства `margin-top` в вашем случае у родительского и дочернего елемента "схлопываются". Если нужен развернутый ответ, **почему** так происходит, то можно
[почитать здесь](http://htmlbook.ru/samlayout/blochnaya-verstka/skhlopyvayushchiesya-otstupy).
Варианты решения:
- можно проставить `border: 1px solid transparent` родителю. И проставить `box-sizing: border-box`, чтобы это не так сильно влияло на размеры блока;
- проставить родителю `overflow:hidden`;
- проставить дочернему `position: relative` и `top: 4rem`

Comment: Спасибо, 3-й вариант помог.
Читал про схлопывание, но моем случае нет отступа у родителя! Поэтому запутался.

Answer (score -1):

Можно добавить родителю `position: relative`, а дочернему `position:absolute` и ему же добавить смещение.